# AutomationID attached property changed

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement

I have a wpf application, 
OnLoaded event I'am attaching an automationId to my FrameworkElement (element):

```
element.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, path);
```

But this automationId is modified somewhere in the code.
I want to add a listner or something  that can help me to debug.
I am waiting for something like

```
AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty+= AutomationIdChanged; 
private void AutomationIdChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         var oldVal =   e.oldValue ;
         var newVal=   e.NewValue;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

***Important:*** You did not mention the target framework. My answer is based on .NET Framework 4.6.2.

You can use the [DependencyPropertyDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor?view=netframework-4.6.2) and call to [AddValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.addvaluechanged?view=netframework-4.6.2#System_ComponentModel_DependencyPropertyDescriptor_AddValueChanged_System_Object_System_EventHandler_) to listen for changes. Unfortunately, this callback function does not provide the old value. However, I will provide a workaround.

I would like to solve it implementing an extension method, named `DebugAutomationIdChanged`:

```
public static class FrameworkElementExt
{
    private static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<FrameworkElement, string> AutomationIdCwt =
        new ConditionalWeakTable<FrameworkElement, string>();

    public static void DebugAutomationIdChanged(this FrameworkElement element)
    {
        var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
            AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty,
            element.GetType()
        );

        descriptor.AddValueChanged(element, delegate
        {
            var currentValue = AutomationProperties.GetAutomationId(element);
            if (AutomationIdCwt.TryGetValue(element, out var oldValue))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"AutomationId changed: '{oldValue}' -> '{currentValue}'");
                AutomationIdCwt.Remove(element);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"AutomationId changed: '{currentValue}'");
            }

            AutomationIdCwt.Add(element, currentValue);
        });
    }
}
```

Later, in your code behind, you can call it like this (some code has been removed to keep simplicity):

```
...
element.DebugAutomationIdChanged();
element.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "fe-01");
...
```